# Request: Add the option to close to review tasks from the "first questions" queue

Tags: feature-request, review-system

Reviewing something in the "First questions" queue, I currently have only three options:

- Leave it (i.e. approve it as is)
- Edit it
- Share feedback, i.e. either

  - Leave a comment asking for clarification
  - Leave a comment with [something else I'm forgetting right now]

What I think is missing is the option to close the question. First questions are more likely than others to be from inexperienced users who do not know (yet) what questions are appropriate here and therefore closing them for any one of the usual reasons should be an acceptable outcome of a review. I can of course click on the question and leave a vote to close there. But that is not counted as completing the review task as (I think) it should.

Comment: Looking at [Glorfindel's report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369017#369017) and a [developer's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369017#comment1231489_369017) it seems that close button should be added. But at least there is (directly in the review) the flag button - which can be used to close directly from the review. Did you try whether this completes the review? (We'll probably have to wait for some suitable review tasks to test this.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I have tried it several times, and it does not complete the review, nor does it enable the 'submit' button to complete the review. Similarly, leaving a comment no longer enables the 'submit' button.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @user44191. Now that's this is settled, a natural question is whether this feature request wouldn't be more suitable as an answer [to the network-wide announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013) rather than on MathOverflow Meta. After all, it is something that would influence the whole network. (It says at the end: "Please leave your feedback and any bugs you may discover related to this release below this post. We will be monitoring this post until Friday, September 10th. Report any further issues after September 10th as new questions on Meta.")

Comment: There are several answers there that seem to note this (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369037, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369017); the mods there say they are working on an answer now.

Comment: I would like to add that a similar issue is with the new "First answers" section: I don't have that screen in front of me, but I remember the impossibility to vote for deletion. This is probably part of the same "let's all be kind to each other" sugar-ish policy.

Comment: @AlexM. The fact that one cannot vote to close questions from the review queue is bad, but please do not make it even worse by posting bogus comments asking for clarification on off-topic but perfectly clear questions such as [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/403127). This is not a solution, and it only serves to confuse the OP. If there is no sensible option, skip the review, and vote or comment on the question manually.

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed. You can now vote to close or flag posts right from the review screen. To complete the review, select “Other action” from the menu.